# Label and select on the same line

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

How can I put my label and my select on the same line in case of this code?

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div>
    <label>Filtrar por Categoria:</label>
       <div id="select-categories"></div>
    </div>
 </div>
```

Javascript:

```
$("#select-categories").each( function ( i ) {
                    var select = $('<select class="form-control"><option value=""></option></select>')
                        .appendTo( $(this).empty() )
                        .on( 'change', function () {
                            table.column( [2] )
                                .search( $(this).val() )
                                .draw();
                        } );

                    table.column([2]).data().unique().sort().each( function ( d, j ) {
                        select.append( '<option value="'+d+'">'+d+'</option>' )
                    } );
                } );
```

Comment: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#forms-inline or https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#forms-horizontal ?

Comment: I tried this but it did not work.

Comment: Tried what? Can't see either inline or horizontal form classes in your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may set your display to inline-block as in the snippet below. Another good way is to use the [Boostrap's column or grid systems](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/examples/grid/). By the way, your JavaScript has references to html elements that you never defined. Hence, I did not use it. In addition, your label was blank to I added some text for testing.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
    <div>
    <label style="display: inline-block;">Filtrar por Categoria:</label>
       <div style="display: inline-block;" id="select-categories">Label</div>
    </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Perfect. Glad to help